# python pandas merge out of memory bus error destroy python environment

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, anaconda

**Edit/Update: running without spark (using only pandas merge) cause Bus error and issue reproduced.**

I do run pyspark with local context and pandas.
After extracting some columns from parquet file I am merging them one by one to the data frame.
Due to issue with date my programs run out of memory (what is expected) due to many to many merge.
After that I see long "call stack" from java. 
And surprise my anaconda installation is broken, each time in different way but it looks like "someone" is writing randomly to some anaconda python files. I have tried 10 times reinstalling and rerunning each time I get failure. If i stop program before running out of memory python environment stays fully functional.

one of the python errors:

```
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 579, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 349, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 207, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 163, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

pyspark:

```
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:841)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2.run(Executor.scala:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 14 more
19/12/02 21:09:18 WARN SparkContext: Ignoring Exception while stopping SparkContext from shutdown hook
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/AbstractChannelHandlerContext$13
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:610)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:465)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.close(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:238)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportServer.close(TransportServer.java:153)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.close(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.stop(BlockManager.scala:1615)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$11.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1974)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1973)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$13
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:370)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:462)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain how you are doing this "merge"?

Comment: The merge is not an issue it just cause consumption of too much memory. But the question is why I am hitting bus error instead  of memory error and afterwards some random files are corrupted.